# Can't display options in select list using *ngFor in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, html-select, ngfor

I'm having trouble displaying the options in a select list. The HTML code is the following:

```
  <select class="selectpicker" (change) = "searchCountry(selectedCountry)" [(ngModel)] = "selectedCountry" data-live-search="true" title = "Selecciona un país">
            <option [ngValue]="object" *ngFor = "let object of countryList" >{{object.Country}}</option> 
  </select>
```

What I'm trying to do is to display the property "Country" (which is a string) of the objects inside the countryList array.
The problem is that there are no options displaying, the select list is empty.

I'm sure that the problem is not with countryList because if I run the following code outside the select element, the Country property displays correctly.

```
<h2>{{countryList[0].Country}}</h2>
```

I've also tried replacing countryList with an array like the following, and it displays correctly, so I'm not sure that the problem is with the select list.

```
countryList: Country[] = ["Argentina", "Chile", "Ecuador];
```

Can it be related to the length of the countryList array? It has 186 elements.

Comment: Unrelated, but try not to use variable names like `object` or `number`. They may (or may not) interfere with JS data types. You could say something like `countryObj`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<option *ngFor="let country of countryList" value="{{country}}">{{country}}</option>
```

in case that countryList is

```
countryList: Country[] = ["Argentina", "Chile", "Ecuador];
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have shown `countryList` is array of strings so you can't use it like `object.Country` simply use object

use like below

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (change) = "searchCountry(selectedCountry)">
    <option [value]="object" *ngFor="let object of countryList">{{object}}</option>
</select>
```

Working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-v6rndj?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I've partially solved the issue.

The code was ok, the problem was the class of the select box in the HTML code. I deleted  'class="selectpicker"' and the select box started showing all the options. This class is from bootstrap-select, maybe it doesn´t support this kind of clauses.

So the code is like this:

```
<select (change) = "searchCountry(selectedCountry)" [(ngModel)] = "selectedCountry"  title = "Selecciona un país">
            <option *ngFor = "let countryName of countryList" >{{countryName.Country}}</option> 
</select>
```

I forgot to mention that countryList's elements are delivered by an HTTP GET method, so replacing it with a string array was not an option. The issue could've been generated by the delay in the HTTP response.

Thanks again.